# Failing to start nfs server

Tags: ubuntu, nfs, dpkg

I'm trying to get nfs working on an Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS. I get the following error:

I've already tried reinstalling nfs-common, nfs-kernel-server and other packages following instructions provided in other forums and couldn't get it working. The installation via dpkg fails everytime due to this.

```
May 17 11:32:44 ocrservernew systemd[1]: Mounting RPC Pipe File System...
May 17 11:32:44 ocrservernew systemd[1]: Mounting NFSD configuration filesystem...
May 17 11:32:44 ocrservernew mount[1962]: mount: unknown filesystem type 'rpc_pipefs'
May 17 11:32:44 ocrservernew systemd[1]: run-rpc_pipefs.mount: Mount process exited, code=exi
May 17 11:32:44 ocrservernew systemd[1]: Failed to mount RPC Pipe File System.
May 17 11:32:44 ocrservernew systemd[1]: Dependency failed for RPC security service for NFS c
May 17 11:32:44 ocrservernew mount[1963]: mount: unknown filesystem type 'nfsd'
May 17 11:32:44 ocrservernew systemd[1]: rpc-gssd.service: Job rpc-gssd.service/start failed 
May 17 11:32:44 ocrservernew systemd[1]: Dependency failed for RPC security service for NFS s
May 17 11:32:44 ocrservernew systemd[1]: rpc-svcgssd.service: Job rpc-svcgssd.service/start f
May 17 11:32:44 ocrservernew systemd[1]: Dependency failed for NFSv4 ID-name mapping service.
May 17 11:32:44 ocrservernew systemd[1]: nfs-idmapd.service: Job nfs-idmapd.service/start fai
May 17 11:32:44 ocrservernew systemd[1]: run-rpc_pipefs.mount: Unit entered failed state.
May 17 11:32:44 ocrservernew systemd[1]: proc-fs-nfsd.mount: Mount process exited, code=exite
May 17 11:32:44 ocrservernew systemd[1]: Failed to mount NFSD configuration filesystem.
May 17 11:32:44 ocrservernew systemd[1]: Dependency failed for NFS server and services.
May 17 11:32:44 ocrservernew systemd[1]: Dependency failed for NFS Mount Daemon.
May 17 11:32:44 ocrservernew systemd[1]: nfs-mountd.service: Job nfs-mountd.service/start fai
May 17 11:32:44 ocrservernew systemd[1]: nfs-server.service: Job nfs-server.service/start fai
May 17 11:32:44 ocrservernew systemd[1]: proc-fs-nfsd.mount: Unit entered failed state.
May 17 11:32:44 ocrservernew sudo[1959]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
```

Any idea what could be going wrong?

Comment: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=152071 it looks like some people had the same issue as you and a reboot fixed the issue. Maybe you can give it a try ?

Comment: @daftaupe Already tried almost everything that I could find on the web. Including this one.

Comment: Ok, then maybe you can update your post, even give the links with the procedures you've followed. So people won't post useless links for you, like I did.

Comment: I suppose you have already tried to upgrade OS with the latest packages and also reboot the system, eventually?